# Button's onClick function does not call window.location when the form input fields have values

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```js
function register() {
  var email = document.getElementById("emailData2").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("passwordData2").value;
  localStorage.setItem("localemail", email);
  localStorage.setItem("localpassword", password);
  window.location.replace("https://accountdemo.netlify.app");
}

document.getElementById("registerButton").addEventListener("click", register);
```

The `window.location.replace()` method only works when I press the button alone. If I fill out the email & password fields and then press the button, it clears the forms, saves the data, and stays on the page it was currently on.

Why is this happening and how do I make it that it redirects when the input fields have been filled out?

HTML:

```
          <div class="inputbox">
            <ion-icon name="mail-outline"></ion-icon>
            <input type="email" id="emailData2" required>
            <label for="">Email</label>
          </div>
          <div class="inputbox">
            <ion-icon name="lock-closed-outline"></ion-icon>
            <input type="password" id="passwordData2" minlength="8" required>
            <label for="">Password</label>
          </div>
          <button id="registerButton">Sign Up</button>
          <div class="register">
```

Comment: Can you include your form HTML, including the button, in your question?

Comment: I suspect you need to add the event listener to the document as the form element is probably updating

Comment: @Nick_O, could you further elaborate?

Comment: Posted below an explanation below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a `<form>` outside the forms? Maybe it's due to the button triggered the form control. You can try

```
function register(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  var email = document.getElementById("emailData2").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("passwordData2").value;
  localStorage.setItem("localemail", email);
  localStorage.setItem("localpassword", password);
  window.location.replace("https://accountdemo.netlify.app");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this with your markup but this would attach the event listener to the document itself rather then the button that I suspect is being updated loosing the attached event

```
function register() {
  var email = document.getElementById("emailData2").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("passwordData2").value;
  localStorage.setItem("localemail", email);
  localStorage.setItem("localpassword", password);
  window.location.replace("https://accountdemo.netlify.app");
}
    
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  const targetId = e.target.id
    
  if(targetId == 'registerButton'){
    register();
  }
});
```